# how to order by desc if i have a table with max that has more than one max values?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

If a have  a table with grades and two students have the same max grade, can i order the result by students name ?

1. Student1 6
2. Student2 5
3. Student3 10
4. Student4 10

How to order by name the students 3 and 4 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *
from students
order by grade, student_name;
```

Comment: i want to select and order only the maximum grades, therefore only the students with 10(without knowing every time which is the biggest grade). any thoughts ?

Comment: @user3316859 the select will first order by grade and only if some grades are identical, the name will be used to order *those* rows. What do you want if there are two more students in your example with grade = 7?